# Best data structure for searching through a collection

Tags: python, data-structures

Currently I have a collection of hundreds of thousands of IDs as integers, and I am performing the following task (lets say this collection is stored in a list `cache` for now):

```
cache = list()
# lets say this cache is populated
for x in range(0,1000000):
    if x not in cache:
        #do_something
```

How expensive is it for me to use a list to search for `not in` something? Would I benefit from using another data structure, and if so which one would be best?

Comment: "Best" is subjective. A set or a dictionary or even a sorted list will typically be faster than an unordered list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). While it's worst case time complexity for `x in cache` would still be O(n), the average case is O(1) ([source](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset for Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you could create the data in `cache` via a generator, you could forgo creating a list on the order of 1e5 and reap the memory savings. Then, you could simply test `x not in` with the following:

```
desired_id = 123456
cache = some_function_to_generate_integer_ids()  # cache is a generator
print desired_id in cache
```

in which `False` will be printed if `desired_id` is not in cache.